# More fundamental approach to a continuity problem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let a continuous $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with this property:

$$\forall x\in \Bbb R\: \forall n\in \Bbb N : f(x)=f\left(x+\frac 1n\right).$$
Show that $f$ is constant.

I 've thought two ways of solving and I will collocate one of them. However I feel that something more fundamental is hidden under that problem. Could someone help?

Comment: I think this is too vague. We can help you with hints or solution-verification - if you clearly specify which aspects of your solution you're not confident of - but asking for us to invent a deeper meaning behind the problem without suggesting why one would exist is too vague in my opinion. *That said*, there is a mild generalisation of this to continuous functions which are constant on a dense subspace or perhaps for continuous functions whose fibre equivalence relation is somehow dense

Comment: Note that $f(x) = f(x-{1 \over n} \lfloor n x \rfloor )$ for all $n$. What does that about $f(x)$?

Comment: For functional equations I like to first look for special values to see if I can find nice properties. Here for $n=1$ we have $f(x)=f(x+1)$ so $f$ is periodic. Now we only have to prove that it's constant on some interval $[x,x+1)$ and it forces $f$ to be constant everywhere else.

Comment: FShrike the first part of your comment seems completely unjustified; I asked specifically if someone can see something fundamental, and "fundamental" about e.g. metric spaces is properties such completeness, compactness etc. or notions such openness, density etc.

Comment: Your second part shows you have understood very well; I think that the extension of constancy from a dense subset of a space to whole space is a very good note. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is easy to see that the property $f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)=f(x)$ must hold for all nonzero integers $n$, whether positive or negative.

Let's prove that the function is constant on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$ for some positive integer $p$ and nonzero integer $q$. Using the property, we have:

$$f(0)=f \left(0+\frac{1}{q} \right)=f\left(\frac{1}{q}\right)$$
$$f\left(\frac{1}{q}\right) = f \left(\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{q} \right) = f \left(\frac{2}{q} \right)$$
$$...$$

We can repeat this $p$ times until we've proven

$$f(0)=f \left(\frac{p}{q} \right)$$

Then, the function is constant on $\mathbb{Q}$ i.e. for all rational numbers $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, $f(r)=f(0)$. Now, let's prove that it's constant on $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. By definition of the real set, there exists a sequence of rational numbers $(r_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $x$. By continuity of $f$, we then have:

$$f(x)=f \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} r_{n} \right) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(r_{n}) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(0) = f(0)$$

Therefore, the function is constant on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f$ is not constant, so there are $x,y\in \Bbb R$ with $x<y$ and $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Let $ε>0$ such that $f(y)-ε>f(x)$. From function 's continuity there exists a $δ>0$ such that $y-δ>x$ and $u\in N_y(δ)\implies f(u)\in N_{f(y)}(ε).$ (1)

By applying multiple times the given property we get
$$...=f(x-2)=f(x-1)=f(x)=f(x+1)=f(x+2)=...,$$
so $f(x)=f(x+m)$, for all $m\in \Bbb Z$. Hence $f(x)=f(x+m+\frac 1n)=f(x+\frac{mn+1}{n})$, for all $n\in \Bbb N,$ or $f(x)=f(x+q)$, for all $q\in \Bbb Q$. (2)

The set $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, so there is a $q\in \Bbb Q \in (y-δ-x, y-x)$, viz $x+q \in (y-δ,y)$. (3)

From (2) and (3) we have $f(x)=f(x+q)$. From (1) and (3) we have that $f(x)\in N_{f(y)}(ε)$, which contradicts with our demand $f(y)-ε>f(x)$.